# Using a make file string variable in CPP file

Tags: c++, makefile

I am using the following code in a make file to access a variable VENDOR_NAME from a CPP file.

`EXTRA_DEFINE += -DVENDOR_NAME=$(VENDOR_NAME)`
`VENDOR_NAME` contains a string.

In my cpp file when I try to use this variable I am getting errors as given below.

`cout << VENDOR_NAME;`

`Feature1.cpp.bak.cpp:8:` 'Default_Vendor' undeclared (first use this function)
`Feature1.cpp.bak.cpp:8:` (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once for

I guess this is because my string does not contain double quotes and compiler is considering content of VENDOR_NAME as a variable.

How to get this variable as a string in my CPP file so that I can use it like I have `#define`ed it?

Thanks...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your makefile is going to create a command line for the compiler. The problem that arises is that if you just surround the value in quotes:

```
EXTRA_DEFINE += -DVENDOR_NAME="$(VENDOR_NAME)"
```

...the shell will see the quotes as simply delineating a command line argument, so it'll probably strip them off (though it can depend on the shell you're using). To prevent that, you'll want to create the argument with escaped quotes:

```
EXTRA_DEFINE += -DVENDOR_NAME="\"$(VENDOR_NAME)\""
```

I think most of the typical shells, at least for Windows and Linux, will accept a back-slash as an escape to preserve the quotes, but I'm sure there's at least one around for which you'll have to do the quoting differently.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: Not any more! :-)

Comment: @Jerry Coffin : Thank you. This is more than enough to save the day.. Good bye to the macros :)

Comment: @NeonGlow: note the second edit through: in case your macro contains spaces, you really want quotes around the outside, containing the escaped quotes, so the shell passes it as one parameter containing quotes.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin : Oh! Thanks for the update. I'm just recompiling with those extra quotes.

Answer (score 3):

Use the preprocessor to turn it into a string.

```
#define stringify( x ) stringify_literal( x )
#define stringify_literal( x ) # x

std::cout << stringify( VENDOR_NAME );
```

Given a preprocessor support for variadic macros (officially C++11, in practice available much longer), `VENDOR_NAME` may include a comma:

```
#define stringify( ... ) stringify_literal( __VA_ARGS__ )
#define stringify_literal( ... ) # __VA_ARGS__

std::cout << stringify( VENDOR_NAME );
```

Comment: Might have issues if `VENDOR_NAME` contains a comma (e.g. "Foo, Inc.").  Probably best to deal with quoting in the makefile itself.

Comment: @Potatoswatter : Thank you very much for your answer. It will be more useful if I can do this in the make file itself. Please let me know if you can help.

Comment: @jamesdin : Thank you for pointing out. Can you further help me on how to do this?